# Issue with merged cells in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have many many Excel workbooks (Excel files) and I have to open each one, because they are from different suppliers. In the active workbook I always need the cells GH327, GH 356, GH358, GH360 (GH cells are merged).

This are multiple Excel files, thats why we cannon put a name of the file in the code. Copy value from this document GH327, GH 356, GH358, GH360

[image]

And I have to copy this GH327, GH 356, GH358, GH360 to another Excel document in F, G, H, I (F are kg, G,H,I are cm). This is the end document:

[image: this is the end document]

Here is a macro with the button that should copy the values from first document. This does not yet work. It copies the value from this Excel file, not the first.

Then I click on the cell I want and press ENTER - then it paste the value - this works!

Code:

MODULE1

```
Sub test()
ReDim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 4)
arr(1, 1) = Range("G327")
arr(1, 2) = Range("G356")
arr(1, 3) = Range("G358")
arr(1, 4) = Range("G360")
With Sheets("Helper")
.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
.Range("A1").Resize(, 4) = arr
.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
End With
End Sub
```

MODUL2

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("B:\eLWIS_EK\NF_INT_-_Pflegeteam_INT    \Verpackungsanlagen\Gesamtliste ab LT 13.07.2017.xlsm")
ReDim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 4)
arr(1, 1) = Range("G327")
arr(1, 2) = Range("G356")
arr(1, 3) = Range("G358")
arr(1, 4) = Range("G360")
wb.Sheets("Verpakungsgewichte").Range("F" &      Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 4) = arr
End Sub
```

[image: CODE TILL NOW]

Comment: Please add the code as text in a code block (this can be done by indenting your code with four spaces) rather than posting an image of your code. Code from images are hard to work with, since they can not be copy pasted to format a proper answer.

Comment: You could use the indirect() function with the filepath and a list of cells with each filename to collect the info you need.

Comment: @Nrzonline - you can also select all the code after pasting it in and tap ctrl+k.

Answer (score 2):

This code might work for you with some tweeks. Make sure all the xlsm files are in the same folder:

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'Loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them

Dim Currentwb As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

NextCode: 'In case of Exit
Currentwb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

myExtension = "*.xlsm*" 'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension) 'Target Path with Ending Extention

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile) 'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    DoEvents 'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
    'This line you might want to fill columns A-E
    Workbooks(Currentwb).Worksheets(1).Range("F" & Workbooks(Currentwb).Worksheets(1).Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("GH327").Value 'Paste your first parameter
    Workbooks(Currentwb).Worksheets(1).Range("G" & Workbooks(Currentwb).Worksheets(1).Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("GH356").Value 'Paste your second parameter
    Workbooks(Currentwb).Worksheets(1).Range("H" & Workbooks(Currentwb).Worksheets(1).Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("GH358").Value 'Paste your thrid parameter
    Workbooks(Currentwb).Worksheets(1).Range("I" & Workbooks(Currentwb).Worksheets(1).Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("GH360").Value 'Paste your fourth parameter
    'This line you might want to fill columns J-L
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False 'Close Workbook without saving
    DoEvents 'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
    myFile = Dir 'Get next file name
Loop

ResetSettings:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

So this just pastes the four values to your final sheet on a new row but you'll have to include how to fill the other columns I assume.

Good luck!

Comment: they never are in same folder. One is on L-Drive, the other on the local disk.

Comment: So make a copy of all files in a specific folder that the vba macro will use - this may also be a form of back-up ... a good idea...